# PHP Shell_Exec not working with variable

Tags: php, shell-exec

I'm trying to pass a variable into shell_exec, I've looked at other tutorials but they still dont help.

I want to pass $var[1] into the shell_exec so it will just display this specific file or directory's information

```
$output = shell_exec('ls -l'.$var[1]);
```

Comment: What is inside `$var[1]`? Can you do `print_r($var[1])` and include the output in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add some whitespace:

```
$output = shell_exec('ls -l '.$var[1]);
                        // ^here
```

Comment: LOL, can't believe i missed that..haha thank you though!

Comment: You're welcome, please mark the answer as correct if it has helped you

Comment: Why does it not display information about a directory? For example if type the name of a folder it doesn't work - will mark as correct once it allows me(10min timer)

Comment: I'm not really sure why it doesn't work without seeing what your variable looks like. But if you echo $output, it should work or at least throw an error

Comment: $var[1] just gets a file or directory name so like test.php etc

Comment: Please try to add the full path to it

Comment: You really should not do that.... 
You should use `scandir` or absolutely anything other than `shell_exec`